# Oracle VM make me install Ubuntu every time I restart the virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu on my Windows computer by using Oracle VM, following the instructions of this page: 
https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox

I can successfully install ubuntu,create a user and open a desktop and go on from there. But every time I log out and log on again, It navigates me to the Ubuntu installing page all over again.

At first, I try to reinstall and go over the same process again. 
It recognized my installation, shown in the picture. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iifrL.png)
I tried reinstalling it 3 times and it did the same thing.

I dont know how to fix this problem and appreciate any answer.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installation you have to remove iso file from VBox. This is same as when you're
installing any OS on your Hostmachine via USB. You have to remove .iso file as you remove USB Stick after the system installed. Remove .iso file

```
Settings --> Storage --> your.iso file
```